# How do you create your own patches for WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am integrating WSO2 Identity Server to a service provider that doesn't understand a AuthnResponse when the namespace prefix is "saml2p". It only accepts "samlp" as namespace prefix in AuthnResponse. This is a bug in the service provider. However, I don't have access to the code on the service provider to fix.

My next idea is to create a patch for this on WSO2 Identity Server. The following steps don't tell you how to create your own patches, get right versions of code &c.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/WSO2+Patch+Application+Process#WSO2PatchApplicationProcess-ApplyingindividualpatchestotheKernel

Is there a procedure I can follow to create a patch on WSO2 Identity Server?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the source of the particular WSO2 IS version that you want to patch and identify the component version that need to be patched. You can look in the pom.xml for the component versions.
Carbon kernel 4.2.0 based products' source can be found at [WSO2 svn](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/)

Example if you wanna patch org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt 4.2.2 component in WSO2 IS 5.0.0 checkout the source of that component from [org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt 4.2.2](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/user-manager/org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt/4.2.2/) and do the necessary changes that you want.
Then build the component with maven. Make sure to use JDK 1.6 if you are using kernel 4.2.0 based products.

You might have to build the [wso2 orbit](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/orbit/branches/4.2.0/),  [carbon kernel](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/), kernel patches and some dependency components as well.

After getting the build jar, you can apply the patch refering to the patching doc you already mentioned.

Refer to [release matrix](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/) for what chunk need to be build for the specific product.